# Pros and Cons of building a relationship model where all table ids are just "_id"?

Tags: schema, primary-key

I have always had the `pk` of the table as this pattern: *lowercase tablename* + Id.

That was what I was taught in college and didn't think about it. When I was challenged on it from someone using `mongo` db (a non-relational db) I couldn't figure out why I have ever done it this way?

The only thing I can think about is that some ORMs have it so that the auto build `pk` columns that normally match this pattern.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no weighty reason to do one or the other.  Both styles are common and work fine.

AFAIK:
Pro: You always know how to join, as foreign keys use the same column name in each table, and join queries are easier to validate.

Con: You can't declare a supertype in your app that has the primary key as a property.  IE it's a relatively common pattern in .NET to have

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

as a common base type for your entitites.

Some may argue that you shouldn't be adding synthetic keys to tables unless there's an actual need, but that's really a different issue.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm going to trust the 26k points and not do anymore research :) - Seeing as I'm not doing that code first db model approach, i'm good!